# VS code remote connection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace'). can some tell me how to fix this problem

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

[VS code return this error when I'm trying to connect VS code to Raspberry Pi4 with remote.ssh. If any one know about this how to fix this problem please let me know.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvAxG.png)

VS code return upper shared screenshot error when I'm trying to connect VS code to Raspberry Pi4 with remote.ssh. If any one know about this how to fix this problem please let me know.